# How to use text-shadow in GTK+?

Tags: css, gtk

I'm trying to add some glowing to the titlebar of the active window using `text-shadow`, but it simply doesn't work. However, I can change the colours and padding:

```
.header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding: 2px; /* Works fine */
}
.header-bar.default-decoration:active {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #FFF; /* Doesn't work */
}
```

It works if I just put it directly, without pseudo-classes, but that sets all windows, not the active one only.

I tried using `:hover` too, but it also didn't work. It seems that properties like `box-shadow` or `text-shadow` don't work within pseudo-classes. How can I make that glowing happen?

Comment: [Your use of text-shadow seems incorrect (three lengths instead of two)?](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/chap-css-properties.html) You can use the GTK+ Inspector to test and debug CSS in real time with error checking, for what it's worth.

Comment: @andlabs, the first two are the positioning relative to the element, the third is the shadow blur.